# Cannot compile the generated code. Please inspect the generated code via this exception's SourceCode property

Tags: xaf, desktop-bridge

I installed my private application which makes use of the Desktop Bridge and Dev Express XAF Winforms, from the Windows Store.
Then I uninstalled it using powershell

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package *jobtalk*
```

Now when I try to reinstall from the store I get

```
Cannot compile the generated code. Please inspect the generated code via this exception's SourceCode property. The following errors occurred: 
(0, 0): Error generating Win32 resource: Access is denied. 
(0, 0): Unable to delete temporary file 'c:\Program Files\WindowsApps\jobtalk.jobtalk_1.0.1.0_neutral__8kpaqbvntb9aj\SBD.JobTalk.Workflow.Win\CSC88B14BFB7D314F00B0D1BB57EFD11.TMP' used for default Win32 resource -- The system cannot find the file specified.
```

[Update]

I think I need to install as administrator somehow.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B203602/cannot-compile-the-generated-code-exception-on-application-start

Comment: http://blog.delegate.at/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem and solution are described at http://blog.delegate.at/

> In order to contain app state, the bridge attempts to capture changes the app makes to AppData. All write to the user's AppData folder (e.g., C:\Users\user_name\AppData), including create, delete, and update, are copied on write to a private per-user, per-app location.